# Generic JavaScript function to access HTML and Asp.net Control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to write a javascript function which can get element by its 'id'

i tried to use this function

```
function getEleById(ele,IsServerElemt) {
      var elmt ;
      if(IsServerElemt) 
          elmt  = '<%='+ ele + '.ClientID%>' ;
      else 
          elmt = ele;

      return document.getElementById(elmt);
}
```

Here we have HTML as well as Asp.Net TextBox.

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and iam trying to call the function as follows

```
var name = getEleById('txtname',true) ;
```

here true specifies that txtname is server control

Is it possible to have a generic javascript method for HTML as well Asp.Net controls.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is `ele` in this context? Is it a string? A control? You definitely can't mix client side and server side scripting the way you have here. This flat out will not compile properly.

Comment: ele is a string.
    var name = getEleById('txtname',true) ;
here true specifies that txtname is server control.

Answer (score 2):

Create your textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can access it by.

```
var textbox= $find("<%=txtname.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: yes i can access the TextBox using $find("<%=txtname.ClientID %>");, but i want to access all the Asp.net controls and HTML control on my page using single javascript function.
var txtname = getEleById(txtname ,true); , here true specifies that its an server side control.

Answer (score 1):

How about using JQuery's CSS selector?

```
1) $('.txtName') //JQuery CSS selector
```

with

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" class="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can put all your script in external JS files this way.[JQuery CSS Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Read through [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx).  It explains the various ways to generate the element's ID.

What I do is create my textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Setting the ClientIDMode to static will set the rendered ID to exactly what you type in the Asp.Net markup.  It will render out as something like this:

```
<input id="txtname" name="?????" />
```

And then your javascript can be written like this:

```
function getEleById(elementID) {
    return document.getElementById(elementID);
}
```

Comment: John thanks for the reply ,the ClientIDMode feature is introduced in .net 4.0. iam using .net 3.5